# Different behaviors on back key pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I've got four activities which the application cycles through. The first one fetches huge amount of data, so I don't wish to do that more than once. Thing is that if user presses back key on last activity, I want to return to the first one without reloading the activity. I'm currently thinking startActivityForResult methods and finish the two previous ones, but there may be a better solution?

Scenario:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasslarn,

The first thing that you must understand is that you have very little choice as to whether an Activity will be reloaded or not. That is determined by the system (largely). With that said, there are a number of things you can do to limit the system's desire to kill the Activity. Additionally, you may use a number of tools at your disposal to limit the impact of such a possible closure

1. Finish every child Activity as it becomes unimportant. This will free resources lowering the need to get rid of unused Activities (even temporarily).
2. Find a simple, but clever way to limit loads.

Based on the information provided, your proposed solution is a viable way to accomplish both. However, I would ask "Is Activity B required to be active while Activity C is open?" If not, you may want to do the following:

1. startActivityForResult(Activity B)
2. When Activity B is done, send result back to Activity A and startActivityForResult(Activity C)
3. Finally, when Activity C is done, you may startActivityForResult(Activity D) and back will work with no effort and you won't have to close the other activities.

Furthermore,  if you press Back on Activity C, you can supply a cancelled result to Activity A forcing a restart of Activity B if you so desire. Depending on the required processing for Activity B, this may not be any hassle at all for your app.

Regardless of how you approach this, I recommend finding a way to cache this data such that onResume(), you may reload quickly if needed. This is because there is NO way to ensure that your original Activity will not be released to make way for the others.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer. I solved it similar to your solution. I do startActivity(B) from A, from B i do startActivity(C). From C i do startActivity(D), and if backkey is pressed in D i finish it and check for that particular result code in C. If that result code was back key, i finish C which will return to B which checks for the same code and finishes also, returning me to A. Maybe not very pretty but it is not much code for it, even though i would prefer something similar to Sana's answer. At least A doesnt reload :)

Comment: Managing multiple Activities is always difficult. I am a HUGE fan of Dialogs. I only use Activities for things that need to be called by other applications unless they are actually different user tasks. But this depends largely on your needs. :) Sana's solution can be quite useful but could be detrimental given your stated "the first one fetches a huge amount of data" as it won't relieve the resources for the other activities; it will just move them.

Comment: As a matter of fact I'm actually a fan of activities :) Greatly appreciate your input, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
    Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(a);
    return true;
```

Activity A will get reordered to front, without creating a new instance. If you want to pass extras through intent , you can get the intent extras in onNewIntent(intent) in Activity A.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but this did unfortunately not work. It didn't change anything whatsoever. Neither did your first answer.